# C++ and assembler: measuring mips

Tags: c++, assembly, inline-assembly

I need to measure millions of operations per second using inline assembler in C++, I'm a newbie in both, so I have some inconsistent output from my program, but I don't know, what number the output should be close to, so I can't really compare them.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <time.h>
#include <stdio.h>

using namespace std;
int main()
{   clock_t t1, t2, t3;
    long n = 500000000;
    long i = 0;

    t1 = clock();
    for(i = 0; i < n; i++){
        __asm__ volatile (
        ".intel_syntax noprefix\n\t"
        "mov ax, bx\n\t"
        );
    }
    t2 = clock();

    for(i = 0; i < n; i++){
        __asm__ volatile (
        ".intel_syntax noprefix\n\t"
        "mov ax, bx\n\t"
        "mov bx, ax\n\t"
        );
    }
    t3 = clock();

    int d1 = t2 - t1;
    int d2 = t3 - t2;
    double operation = (d2 - d1) / (double) n;

    cout <<"n + loop:    " << d1 << " ms" << endl;
    cout <<"2n + loop:   " << d2 << " ms" << endl;
    cout << "n operations:  " << d2 - d1 << " ms" << endl;
    cout << "1 operation:  " << operation << " ms" << endl;
    cout << "mops:  "<< 1000 / (operation * 1024 * 1024) <<endl;
    return (0);
}
```

And output is like:

```
n + loop:    1590078 ms
2n + loop:   1598367 ms
n operations:  8289 ms
1 operation:  1.6578e-05 ms
mops:  57.5265
```

or

```
n + loop:    1593836 ms
2n + loop:   1593969 ms
n operations:  133 ms
1 operation:  2.66e-07 ms
mops:  3585.24
```

or

```
n + loop:    1582123 ms
2n + loop:   1592557 ms
n operations:  10434 ms
1 operation:  2.0868e-05 ms
mops:  45.7003
```

So my question basically is: is it a proper way to measure, even roughly, mips?

Comment: That's a tough one. You're probably using multi-core CPU also, which complicates things. The result will output vastly different times because the kernel will execute instructions from other programs at the same time that your program is running.

Comment: @a_caban thank you, that makes things much clearer now, so, as I understand, C++ and inline asm isn't the way to go for such calculations?

Comment: To be honest, I'm not quite sure what the best means is for that type off measurement. From your assembly it looks like you're trying to measure an old 386 processor for the time it takes to perform a register move operation. If your processor had only one core and you wrote a pure assembly image that ran at boot time then you could make the claim that "fast instructions run a million times complete X second" with some certainty.

Comment: http://www.agner.org/optimize/#testp